# How can I flip a coin?

Tags: unity

I am working in unity and have flattened out a cylinder object to make a coin for a 3d coin flipping game, but I am not sure how to get the coin to flip when the player swipes across it and allow for a double flip if the player swipes over it a second time while in mid air.

here is what I have tried:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
public class CoinFlip : MonoBehaviour { 

    private Vector3 start; 

    private void Start() { 
        start = gameObject.transform.position; 
    } 

    void Update() { 
        transform.position += transform.right * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 0.45f) * -0.025f; 
    } 

    void OnEnable() { 
        gameObject.transform.position = start; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could get the swipe's direction and apply a torque force to the coin with Rigidbody.AddForce(swipeDirection, forceMode) [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html], considering that the coin had a Rigidbody (which would be most probably the case given what you try to achieve), and also an upward force so the coin rises. For the case of a second coin flip, the same coul be applied.

Comment: What have you tried so far, based on the tutorials and past Q&A you've consulted?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the coin to behave like a physical coin, then you might want to leave this to the physics engine.

Add a gravity-engabled [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) to the coin and place the coin on top of a static Plane so it doesn't fall into oblivion.

Now, in order to catapult it into the air, write a script which calls [`Rigidbody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) with an appropriate upward force when the user performs an action.

The effect should be that the coin is catapulted into the air but keeps its orientation. That's a start. But you wanted to *flip* the coin. That means it should rotate. The reason it doesn't rotate is because AddForce adds a force which acts exactly on the center of mass of the rigidbody. So it all goes into acceleration and nothing goes into rotation. In order to change that, you can use [`Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) to apply the force with an offset to the center of mass. That should result in a rotation.

The next two problems you have to solve are:

- How do you prevent the player from launching the coin off-screen?
- How do you detect which side is up when the coin lands?

But these are material for new questions.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about making the coin a heads up or down thing I did want to give extra points if the player was able to make it land on its edge. I have been fighting with the physics of the coin though and it had been falling into oblivion. I am working with 3d gamekit from the asset store and had made a platform that the coin kept falling through. I will try your methods though to see if that is where I am having issues